# Interpretation of generalized eigenvalue/vectors in spectral graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Let us say I have a symmetric graph adjacency matrix $A$, a degree matrix $D$, a Laplacian $L(=D-A)$. I have a generalized eigenvalue equation $Av=\lambda Lv$. Do the eigenvalues/vectors produced in this way have any graph theoretic interpretations?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that $D^{-1}Av=\frac\lambda{1+\lambda}v$? Then $v$ is an eigenvector of a weighted version of $A$...

Comment: It seems like the generalized eigenvalue problem is good for approximations. How exactly, I don't know. The only thing I could dig up was a one-sentence mention in one of Dan Spielman's slide presentations: http://cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/sgta/SpectTut.pdf